# jQuery if any of a certain class is hidden perform a task, else, perform another task

Tags: jquery, if-statement

Is there a way to test if a certain element (.container) is hidden, in a whole document? Such as (which doesn't work properly):

```
$(".showall").click(
    function () {
        if ($(".container").is("hidden"))
                {perform a task}
            else
                {return false;}
    });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you want to test if *at least one* of the `.container` elements is hidden.

If so, you can use the `:hidden` selector, and check the `length` property to see how many were returned.

```
$(".showall").click(
    function () {
        if ($(".container:hidden").length)
             // found at least one hidden
        else
             // didn't find any hidden
    });
```

If you wanted to test to see if *all* were hidden, use the `:visible` selector like this:

```
$(".showall").click(
    function () {
        if ($(".container:visible").length)
             // found at least one visible
        else
             // didn't find any visible
    });
```

Comment: Why was this down voted? What is incorrect? The question isn't entirely clear. OP said *in a whole document* which sounds like OP is testing for *any* or *all* hidden or visible.

Answer (score 0):

You mean to use is visible:

```
$(".showall").click(
    function () {
        if ($('.container').is(":visible") == false)
                {perform a task}
            else
                {return false;}
    });
```